# Make menu go to the end of page-width

Tags: html, css, menu, width

http://jsfiddle.net/x2jsqbmf/1/

so... My brain has just stopped working.
 What I want to create is a menu that goes to the end of the screen (no matter what resolution i'm using). I've made a comment on the section that needs assistance. (row 64)

```
.menu > li:nth-child(3){
width:70%;
overflow-x:hidden;
float:left;
margin-top:0;
position:relative;
```

}
    help is much appreciated!
http://puu.sh/cUlPx/90c4b578fa.png
this is what I want. The last section nth-child(3) is going to be infinite in width. (or automatically adapt to screen-width)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 .menu > li {
float: left;
 height: 100%;
width: 30%; 
width: calc((100% - 90px) / 5);
width: -moz-calc((100% - 90px) / 5);
width: -webkit-calc((100% - 90px) / 5);
position:relative;
 z-index:1;
}
.menu > li:nth-child(3){
margin-top:0;
width:100%;
z-index:0;
position:absolute;
height:90px;
 } 



.menu > li.home {
background: #00CCFF url(../images/home.png) center no-repeat; /* detta var 3E454D innan */
width: 90px;
}

.menu > li.current {
 background-color: #00CCFF !important; /* !important VS .menu li:hover #F2762E */
 box-shadow: none !important;
-moz-box-shadow: none !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: none !important;

 }
```

Updated Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x2jsqbmf/4/

thanks to everyone who participated in trying to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting something like this

```
.menu > li:nth-child(3){
float:right;
position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Nope, that is not what i'm after. I want the last section of the menu, to have infinite width. eg. It's always going to touch the edge of the screen.

Comment: can you please provide me a mock up ?

Comment: mockup: http://puu.sh/cUlPx/90c4b578fa.png
(if the very edge of the menu was touching the edge of the browser).

Comment: what do you think of this idea:
Making a new div, with 100% width. Then using z-index to position this Div underneath the "menu" itself, this way. Everything "should" be working, regardless of browser-width ?

Comment: @Joel try that out and let us know

Comment: Sure @Joel thats great